# Creating a Custom Hardware Interface for a Two-Wheeled Mobile Robot for ros2_control?

Tags: ros2, control, mobile-robot, ros2-control, ros2-controllers

I am in the process of developing a custom two-wheeled mobile robot with differential control, and I want to integrate it with the ROS 2 ecosystem, specifically leveraging **ros2_control**. I understand that **ros2_control** provides a framework to connect any hardware to ROS 2, but I am having some challenges with where and how to start for specific/custom robot configuration.

**Robot Details:**

- Two drive wheels with individual motor controllers.
- The robot uses differential control for maneuvering.
- Velocity control mechanism for each wheel.
- Encoders on each wheel for feedback.

**Questions:**

1. What are the fundamental steps to create a custom hardware interface for a differential-controlled robot to use with **ros2_control**?
2. How can I expose the readings from the wheel encoders to the **joint_states** topic within the ROS 2 ecosystem?

I've already gone through the official **ros2_control** documentation, and understood that I need to use **ros2_control** tags in my robot's URDF to set up the hardware interfaces and that I need to write YAML file to configure controllers. I'd greatly appreciate insights or experiences from those who have tackled the creation of the **hardware interface**, especially in the context of wheeled robots and encoder data integration.

Thank you in advance for your guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [diff_drive example](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_2/doc/userdoc.html), this should answer question 2.

About how to write a hardware_component [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J02jEKawE5U) could help you with the first steps, or have a look at [this step-by-step guide](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control/hardware_interface/doc/writing_new_hardware_component.html).